# Deleting entity in in-memory H2 database

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

In my test I have an in-memory H2 DB and I want to test deleting an entity.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REPORT_BLOB")
public class BlobInfoDBVO {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "REPORT_ID")
  private long reportId;

}
```

Test code

```
 @Test
  void deleteByReportId() {
    var reportId = 1L;

    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    tx.begin();

    var blobInfo = new BlobInfoDBVO();
    blobInfo.setReportId(reportId);
    em.persist(blobInfo);

    tx.commit();
    tx.begin();

    BlobInfoDBVO findByReportId1 = em.find(BlobInfoDBVO.class, reportId);
    assertNotNull(findByReportId1); // ---- OK

    var getByReportId1 = blobInfoDao.getByReportId(reportId);
    assertTrue(getByReportId1.isPresent()); // ---- OK

    tx.commit();
    tx.begin();

    blobInfoDao.deleteByReportId(reportId);

    tx.commit();
    tx.begin();

    var getByReportId2 = blobInfoDao.getByReportId(reportId);
    assertFalse(getByReportId2.isPresent()); // ---- OK

    BlobInfoDBVO findByReportId2 = em.find(BlobInfoDBVO.class, reportId);
    assertNull(findByReportId2); // ---- FAILS

    tx.commit();
  }
```

And here is my DAO code to find and delete an entity by `reportId`:

```
public class BlobInfoDaoImpl {

  EntityManager em;

  public BlobInfoDaoImpl(EntityManager em) {
    super();
    this.em = em;
  }

  public Optional<BlobInfoDBVO> getByReportId(long reportId) {
    var query =
        em.createQuery(
            """
            select blobInfo
              from BlobInfoDBVO blobInfo
             where blobInfo.reportId = :reportId
            """,
            BlobInfoDBVO.class);
    query.setParameter("reportId", reportId);
    return query
        .getResultStream()
        .findFirst();
  }

  public void deleteByReportId(long reportId) {
    var query =
        em.createQuery(
            """
            delete from BlobInfoDBVO
             where reportId = :reportId
            """);
    query.setParameter("reportId", reportId);

    query.executeUpdate();
  }
}
```

After deleting an entity, I cannot find it anymore using manually executing a query by calling my DAO (`getByReportId`) what is correct and expected.

But when I use a `find` method from an `EntityManager` using a `reportId` field as a primary key (it's marked as `@Id`) - it still returns not deleted entity, even if transaction was commited before.

Any idea?

hobernate-core 5.6.14

quarkus-test-h2 2.14.0.Final

Comment: Does doing `EntityManager.clear()` to clear the cache after the delete's commit help things?

Comment: Hi, yes, it has helped! Thank you! Add an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JPA `EntityManager` may be caching the result from your query, even across transactions (not sure whether the spec says this should or should not happen).  Try doing an `EntityManager.clear()` to clear its cache after the delete's commit so that the subsequent queries go to the real database.